# Encountered an unexpected error when attempting to resolve tag helper directive '@addTagHelper'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community edition, and I've created an ASP.NET MVC 5 project.

When I open a view (`Index` of `Home` or any other), it shows first three lines of the page underlined with red as a syntax issue. Here is the error:

> Encountered an unexpected error when attempting to resolve tag helper
>   directive '@addTagHelper' with value 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.TagHelpers.UrlResolutionTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor'.
>   Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The screenshot:

[image: @addTagHelper error message]

When I build the project, it build successfully. When I run it, it shows a lot of errors, but it runs the application.

[image: Index View with errors]

> The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.AspNet' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

and

> '_Page_views_home_index_cshtml.ExecuteAsync()': no suitable method
>   found to override

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Having the exact same issue today.  Upgraded the project to MVC 5 and C# 6 and now every view is hosed with this crap.  Site still works and compiles fine, but it makes development very difficult.

Comment: I'll also add I'm using VS 2015 Enterprise and have updated MS.CodeDom to 1.0.1 (latest) and MS.Net.Compilers to 1.1.1 (latest) as well.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Here's how I fixed the issue:

First, [reset the Visual Studio Component Cache](https://web.archive.org/web/20180726232921/http://withmartin.net/how-visual-studios-component-model-cache-can-be-a-pain/) by closing Visual Studio and deleting this folder:

> C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

And finally, check the `web.config` files and change:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    ...
</appSettings>
```

to

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    ...
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Create a new MVC project and compare the two web.config files with the ones in your project.  Pay special attention to the version numbers of `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` and `System.Web.Mvc` to make sure they're up to date as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but the above didn't work.  I also deleted all 4 files in the Component cache which didn't work. I noticed that the line below
`<appSettings>` was set to `false`.  I changed it to `true` and the red squigs were gone.

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
```

Comment: I've tried changing the value to true and this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the reference to System.Web.Mvc had disappeared.

There was lots of errors in the cshtml files but it would compile and run.   Then I found that I had an error in the xxxcontrollers.cs file trying inherit controllers.

Seems it could compile because the dll was in bin already but it was giving errors.

I did not relish having to rebuild this project.  That would be days and days.