# Missing Assembly

Tags: asp.net-core

Can someone please help, I've managed to uninstall the wrong Nuget package and now I have the following error:

> Error  CS0234  The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you tried re-adding it? If you're using source control it should be easy enough to undo the changes.

Comment: Please try my solutions , if it doesn't work. Please tell me the version of your visual studio and the version of .net core used in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to add some assembly by `NuGet Package Manager`, or clear `MEF Component Cache`.**

**Suggestions:**

1. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core`, then rebuild.

   [image]
2. `Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Framework`, then rebuild.

   [image]
3. Try to `Clear MEF Component Cache`.

   [To fix this I deleted my Visual Studio's component model cache folder which can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42412391/7687666)
4. Upgrad to the latest stable version of Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Thank you, that sorted that issue out but now when I run through iisexpress I am getting ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure. This happened when I found out GoDaddy only host ASP.Net Core 2.0 on Plesk so I changed my target framework. Don't know what to do now. Any help please...